# How to extract substring in Groovy?

Tags: string, syntax, groovy, substring

I have a Groovy method that currently works but is *real* ugly/hacky looking:

```
def parseId(String str) {
    System.out.println("str: " + str)
    int index = href.indexOf("repositoryId")
    System.out.println("index: " + index)
    int repoIndex = index + 13
    System.out.println("repoIndex" + repoIndex)
    String repoId = href.substring(repoIndex)
    System.out.println("repoId is: " + repoId)
}
```

When this runs, you might get output like:

```
str: wsodk3oke30d30kdl4kof94j93jr94f3kd03k043k?planKey=si23j383&repositoryId=31850514
index: 59
repoIndex: 72
repoId is: 31850514
```

As you can see, I'm simply interested in obtaining the `repositoryId` value (everything after the `=` operator) out of the String. Is there a more efficient/Groovier way of doing this or this the only way?

Comment: Use a regular expression to capture the pattern you're looking for

Answer (score 21):

There are a lot of ways to achieve what you want. I'll suggest a simple one using `split`:

```
sub = { it.split("repositoryId=")[1] }

str='wsodk3oke30d30kdl4kof94j93jr94f3kd03k043k?planKey=si23j383&repositoryId=31850514'

assert sub(str) == '31850514'
```

Comment: I get an error: **no such property sub for  class: org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated**

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky are you running it from a script? try adding a `def` in front of `sub`.

Comment: @Will, how do i get only the say next number and not the trailing ones after that? your solution is returning everything after the keyword. e.g. i have the String,  "Request ID for the current retrieve task: 09Sg00000052eIJEAY [sf:retrieve] Waiting for server to finish processing the request...". I am trying to get only "09Sg00000052eIJEAY".  I know i have to modify the index. But i can't figure so far

Comment: Got it!!!  def sub = { it.split("current retrieve task: ")[1][0..18] } ....  Upvoted the answer :)

Answer (score 16):

Using a regular expression you could do

```
def repositoryId = (str =~ "repositoryId=(.*)")[0][1]
```

The `=~` is a regex matcher

Comment: the `=` is missing :)

Answer (score 2):

or a shortcut regexp - if you are looking only for single match:

```
String repoId = str.replaceFirst( /.*&repositoryId=(\w+).*/, '$1' )
```

Answer (score 2):

All the answers here contains regular expressions, however there are a bunch of string methods in `Groovy`.

| String Function | Sample | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| contains | myStringVar.contains(substring) | Returns true if and only if this string contains the specified sequence of char values |
| equals | myStringVar.equals(substring) | This is similar to the above but has to be an exact match for the check to return a true value |
| endsWith | myStringVar.endsWith(suffix) | This method checks the new value contains an ending string |
| startsWith | myStringVar.startsWith(prefix) | This method checks the new value contains an starting string |
| equalsIgnoreCase | myStringVar.equalsIgnoreCase(substring) | The same as equals but without case sensitivity |
| isEmpty | myStringVar.isEmpty() | Checks if myStringVar is populated or not. |
| matches | myStringVar.matches(substring) | This is the same as equals with the slight difference being that matches takes a regular string as a parameter unlike equals which takes another String object |
| replace | myStringVar.replace(old,new) | Returns a string resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar |
| replaceAll | myStringVar.replaceAll(old_regex,new) | Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement |
| split | myStringVar.split(regex) | Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression |