# Parse values in Groovy script from yml file

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have the following yml output from running a shell command:

```
repositories:
- createdAt: '2023-09-07T22:30:50+00:00'
  encryptionConfiguration:
    encryptionType: AES256
  imageScanningConfiguration:
    scanOnPush: false
  imageTagMutability: MUTABLE
  registryId: '12344'
  repositoryArn: arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:12344
  repositoryName: test-registry
  repositoryUri: 12344
```

I use this groovy script to get the value:

```
def profile = "ecr"
def region = "us-east-1"
def cmd_output = "aws ecr describe-repositories --profile $profile --region $region --output yaml".execute()
def awk_cmd_output = cmd_output | ['awk', '/repositoryName:/ {print $2}'].execute()
def repo_names = awk_cmd_output.text.tokenize().reverse()
return repo_names
```

But for some reason the value `test-registry` is not parsed properly.

Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: "is not parsed properly" How is it currently parsed?

Comment: I get empty output.

Comment: You did not get an error like here: https://onecompiler.com/groovy/3zm5ma4k8 ?   (I am new too Groovy, so ... )

Comment: This groovy script is used into jenkins plugin `Active Choices`. I get empty dropdown.

Comment: Try to use: `def repo_names = test-registry`, when that works you do know that your awk code is not correct.

Comment: I tried this but again it's null: https://onecompiler.com/groovy/3zm5ng2jq

Comment: Debugging shows that some check is wrong ("I as here" is not printed), see: https://onecompiler.com/groovy/3zm5q332z

Comment: Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Sorry, Groovy is tooo groovy for me. (tried, but was not able to get [How to extract substring in Groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25064101/how-to-extract-substring-in-groovy) working)

Comment: Why use awk and not groovys yaml parser?

Comment: Can you show me code example please?

Comment: `new YamlSlurper().parseText(cmd_output).repositories[0].repositoryName`